# Getting the same output, even if I give the different inputs in my C program

Tags: c, string, memory, time

Date and Epoch values are not updating. I am getting the same output even if I give the different inputs for number of times. Can anyone please tell me the solution for this?

And also my string is partially printing, not printing full date in first printf() statement. I want to print it like 2017-04-23. But it is printing only 2017. How can I print the whole date?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void toInt(char []);
long EpochValue(char []);

int y1,m1,d1;
static int i=1;

int main()
{
    long epoch;
    char a[20] = "2017-04-23";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %ld\n",a,EpochValue(a));

    char b[20] = "2016-12-11";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %ld\n",b,EpochValue(b));

    char c[20] = "2014-09-08";
    printf("epoch value of %s is %ld\n",c,EpochValue(c));

    return 0;
}

long EpochValue(char a[])
{
    int month,date,year;
    struct tm *day;
    time_t epoch,today;


    char *token = strtok(a,"-");
    while(token!=NULL){
        toInt(token);
        token = strtok(NULL,"-");
    }

    year = y1;
    month = m1;
    date = d1;

    printf("\nyear: %d\n month %d\n day %d\n",year,month,date);

    time(&today);
    day = localtime(&today);
    day->tm_mon  = month-1;
    day->tm_mday = date;
    day->tm_year = year-1900;

    epoch = mktime(day);

    printf("u were born on %d/%d/%d\n",date,month,year);

    return epoch;;
}

void toInt(char a[]) {

    if(i==1)
            y1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==2)
            m1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==3)
            d1 = atoi(a);

    i++;
}
```

I am getting the same Output every time, you can see below

```
year: 2017
month 4
day 23
u were born on 23/4/2017
epoch value of 2017 is 1492995157

year: 2017
month 4
day 23
u were born on 23/4/2017
epoch value of 2016 is 1492995157

year: 2017
month 4
day 23
u were born on 23/4/2017
epoch value of 2014 is 1492995157
```

Comment: You need reset `i`.

Comment: can you explain me briefly, I didn't get your point?

Comment: Try Put `i = 1;` after `time_t epoch,today;`

Comment: no change..... @BLUEPIXY

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/s9C5FR)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in `void toInt(char a[])` function. Remember that in your program `i` is a `static` global variable. So, when the `void toInt(char a[])` function is called first three times in `long EpochValue(char a[])` function's while loop. The value of i exceeds 3. Now next time when the function is called again, all the three conditions in `void toInt(char a[])` function will be `false` because `i` will be greater than 3.

```
void toInt(char a[]) {  /* Conditions below are true only when function called thrice for first time, that's why you see the same first values again and again. */

    if(i==1)     
            y1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==2)
            m1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==3)
            d1 = atoi(a);

    i++;
}
```

Try using this one, I have imposed a new condition in your function to handle this problem:

```
void toInt(char a[]) {

    if(i==1)
            y1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==2)
            m1 = atoi(a);
    if(i==3)
            d1 = atoi(a);

    if(i==3)   /* Making Sure that Value of i is reset after reaching three */
    {
        i=1;
    }
    else
    {
    i++;
    }

}
```

And this solves your problem :)

Comment: +1 It's working, thank you @HN Learner, will you tell me the reason why string date is not printing fully?

Comment: My pleasure ! 
And I don't think there is anything wrong with the date string. Please let me know if Im missing something. Can you explain your question?

Comment: @C-Programmer That's because you are using `strtok`. It changes the string (Replace the delimiter with `'\0'`. E.g `2017-` ==> `2017\0`).